# Windows UWP: Single Process Background Bluetooth Task Not Triggering

Tags: windows, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy, background-task

I'm registering Bluetooth LE as a grouped background task, but I'm not sure why the background task doesn't even trigger. It appears to be registered correctly when I check "Get-AppBackgroundTask" in a powershell. This is how I'm registering the task:

```
Guid bleServiceGuid = new Guid("xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxx");

private void RegisterGroupedBackgroundTask(){
  BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherTrigger bleTrigger = new 
  BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherTrigger(); bleTrigger.AdvertisementFilter.Advertisement.ServiceUuids.Add(bleServiceGuid);
        bleTrigger.SignalStrengthFilter.InRangeThresholdInDBm = -65;
        bleTrigger.SignalStrengthFilter.OutOfRangeThresholdInDBm = -75;
        bleTrigger.SignalStrengthFilter.OutOfRangeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);
        bleTrigger.SignalStrengthFilter.SamplingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

var bluetoothLeTask = BackgroundTasksConfiguration.RegisterBackgroundTask(null,
                                                  BackgroundTasksConfiguration.GroupedBackgroundTaskName,
                                                  bleTrigger,
                                                  null,
                                                  group);
}
```

The problem is that the Background Task entry point is never reached:

```
  BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral = null;
  IBackgroundTaskInstance _taskInstance = null;

public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance){

deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
        _taskInstance = taskInstance;

var details = _taskInstance.TriggerDetails as Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Background.BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherTriggerDetails; 
     if (details != null){

      //Get rssi values....
     }    
 }
```

How can I trigger a bluetooth le background task when the external peripheral device is advertising with a service guid in range?

Answer (score 0):

Got this working...for some reason the application doesn't like it if I just filter by an advertising service guid. I had to filter by manufacturer data for the triggers to fire:

```
 bleTrigger = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherTrigger();
        bleTrigger.AdvertisementFilter.Advertisement.ManufacturerData.Add(new BluetoothLEManufacturerData()
        {
            CompanyId = 76 // Apple Bluetooth SIG 
        });
```